# Is there a driver downloader for Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, installation, download

Every now and then someone asks me to format his computer and install some windows version. As you all know no drivers are installed by default other than the very basic. I download the wifi driver for the laptop, and I update windows, many drivers are installed in the process. Some are installed from the device manager.

But some others, like the Ethernet, often you have to look for it on google and check the model of the laptop and stuff like that.

Is there a reliable free drivers downloader that checks the missing drivers and try to install them automatically? No paid software, I'd rather do it manually, it's a silly task, not worth paying for.

Comment: Are you looking for this kinda stuff? `http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/automatically-get-recommended-drivers-and-updates-for-your-hardware`

Comment: @Vembu  page not found, I'm currently using linux, is that the reason or is the link broken?

Comment: Oops! here is the link `http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/automatically-get-recommended-drivers-and-updates-for-your-hardware` . Opening up in Linux should not be an issue.

Comment: @Vembu no i'm not looking for that, windows is unable to find the drivers, i'm looking for a third party software that do the job better than windows so that i don't have to go to websites and download them manually

Comment: The last place to go for drivers for hardware that came originally installed in your machine are the device manufacturer web sites or third party driver download sites.  Those drivers often won't work with OEM versions of devices.  Get everything from the computer manufacturer's web site unless it isn't available there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freeware - [IOBit Driver Booster](http://www.iobit.com/driver-booster.php)

I've tried it to see if it appears to be finding the right things, & it does seem to be - rather than those that claim your 1992 CD-ROM drive needs an update but you'll have to pay 25 bucks to do it.

Having said that, I've not tested it extensively, so ymmv.

Comment: trying it now, fingers crossed, so far didnt ask me for money

Comment: seems like it worked, still 1 driver, the generic bluetooth driver, didnt find it, i guess googling only 1 is fine, i liked that software. but someone didn't like my question nor your answer so he voted both down and was too busy to leave a comment explaining why :)

Comment: some people just hate the 'easy way out' & think it can't possibly work ;-)

Comment: I've not found software that looks for the OEM drivers at the computer manufacturer's site.  Even the best ones look for the "retail" version drivers, which often don't work.  Most seem to find drivers older than what is already on the machine and think they are newer.  Every one I have looked at wants to replace virtually every driver on the machine when a check of the OEM drivers says they are all up to date.

Comment: I don't have any OEM machines here, all self-builds, full licenses etc. The tests I've done [not by any means exhaustive] show it to be 'smarter' than Windows update & the ones I've tracked down do actually appear to be the latest versions. I'm not claiming it's the be-all & end-all of driver hunters, just seems to be benign & doesn't offer 8-year old chipset drivers that some seem to.